# How to interpret a binary integer as ternary (base 3)?

Tags: math, binary, numbers, bit-manipulation

My CPU register contains a binary integer `0101`, equal to the decimal number 5:

0101 ( 4 + 1 = 5 )

I want the register to contain instead the binary integer equal to decimal 10, as if the original binary number 0101 were ternary (base 3) and every digit happens to be either 0 or 1:

0101 ( 9 + 1 = 10 )

How can i do this on a contemporary CPU or GPU with 1. the fewest memory reads and 2. the fewest hardware instructions?

Comment: What language are you working with? What is the datatype of the number? An array? A sequence of characters?

Comment: How is the binary number given? as an int? or as an array of numbers?

Comment: "binary" means with only digits 0 and 1, and "ternary" means with only digits 0, 1, and 2. I have a binary integer in a CPU register and I want the register to contain the binary integer that represents the input value interpreted as a ternary (base 3) number. for example if the input is binary 10, the output should be binary 11 because the input is interpreted as a ternary number with decimal value 3.

Comment: @bmcnett: There was no mysterious stranger. Another user of the SO community edited your question for clarity. It's much better now than the original version. Questions (and answers!) are not locked and can be improved by others, too, not only the original posters.

Comment: Please also try to answer the other questions, made in comments (e.g. you mention CPU and GPU but not what language you are using, is it Assembly, C, some other?). Just mentioning CPU does not help others to understand you. Without a Processing Unit, it's very hard to run code anyway...

Comment: doesn't matter which language, as my aim is fewest memory accesses, followed by fewest instructions. HLSL or C++ are OK I suppose. I don't agree with all the edits to my question. in particular, scrubbing the word "ternary" and adding "bit string" when this is a low level bithack kinda thing.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to reinterpret the bits as if they were ternary digits? If so, do nothing (but afterwards doing math with them will be nontrivial).

Comment: I want the binary value that corresponds to the ternary value, so I can't simply do nothing. naively I could multiply bit 1 by 3, bit 2 by 9, bit 3 by 27, etc. and add the results, but I think there's a faster way.

Comment: There is a faster way - create a base 81 lookup table for each group of 4 digits, and process 4 digits at a time. It's incrementally faster, but significantly so.

Answer (score 2):

Use an accumulator. C-ish Pseudocode:

```
var accumulator = 0
foreach digit in string
   accumulator = accumulator * 3 + (digit - '0')
return accumulator
```

To speed up the multiply by 3, you might use ((accumulator << 1) + accumulator), but a good compiler will be able to do that for you.

If a large percentage of your numbers are within a relatively small range, you can also pregenerate a lookup table to make the transformation from base2 to base3 instantaneous (using the base2 value as the index). You can also use the lookup table to accelerate lookup of the first N digits, so you only pay for the conversion of the remaining digits.

Answer (score -1):

This C program will do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
 int binary = 5000; //Example
 int ternary = 0;
 int po3 = 1;

 do
   {
    ternary += (binary & 1) * po3;
    po3 *= 3;    
   }
 while (binary >>= 1 != 0);

 printf("%d\n",ternary); 
}
```

The loop compiles into this machine code on my 32-bit Intel machine:

```
 do
   {
    ternary += (binary & 1) * po3;
0041BB33  mov         eax,dword ptr [binary]  
0041BB36  and         eax,1  
0041BB39  imul        eax,dword ptr [po3]  
0041BB3D  add         eax,dword ptr [ternary]  
0041BB40  mov         dword ptr [ternary],eax  
    po3 *= 3;    
0041BB43  mov         eax,dword ptr [po3]  
0041BB46  imul        eax,eax,3  
0041BB49  mov         dword ptr [po3],eax  
   }
 while (binary >>= 1 != 0);
0041BB4C  mov         eax,dword ptr [binary]  
0041BB4F  sar         eax,1  
0041BB51  mov         dword ptr [binary],eax  
0041BB54  jne         main+33h (41BB33h)
```

For the example value (decimal 5000 = binary 1001110001000), the ternary value it produces is 559899.